# passing array of values in sql select statement of where condition

Tags: php, sql, moodle

```
$sql = "select id from table_name ";

$result = mysql_query($sql); 

$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
 $data[] = $row[id];

}
```

/* $data contains id's fetched from sql query from db.now i want to pass this id's(array of values) in $data array one by one to below select query in where condition and obtain desired result for each id.My question is how to pass an array of values to the below select statement  I dont know how to do this.Any help is greatly appreciated.*/

```
$query = "select * from table where id1 = $data[] ";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "select * from table where `id1` in (" . implode(', ', $data) . ")";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the cross database function in Moodle called get_in_or_equal()

```
list($where, $params) = $DB->get_in_or_equal($data, SQL_PARAMS_NAMED);
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM {table}
        WHERE $id {$where}"
$records = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IN` clause.
When you are totally sure you only have numeric values in your `$data` array. You can do the following:

```
$query = "select * from table where id1 IN(" . implode(',', $data) . ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$comma_separated = implode(",", $data);
if ($comma_separated != "")
    $query = "select * from table where id1 IN($comma_separated)";
```